# Which game engine allows you to add a c++ compiler within a game?

Tags: game-engine, game-development

I was thinking of writing a game that teaches you the basics of c++, but in order for me to do that, I need to add a compiler that takes the input of the user and checks the correctness of the solved problem by using a set of predefined tests.

Comment: Why can't you invoke an external compiler?

Comment: [Asking for programming language is off-topic](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256696/asking-for-programming-languages).

Answer (score 2):

You could pack a compiler inside your game. Allow the user to write all of their code and then compile it through the command line.
Something like this:

```
g++ -o helloworld.exe test1.cpp
```

After that, you can invoke it through the Windows command line

```
helloworld.exe>result.txt
```

Which will run the program and output the result in a .txt file